# Getting error while trying to update SDK manager through by the command sdkmanager --update

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
```

Getting error while  trying to update `SDK` manager through by the command `sdkmanager --update`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install android studio then do

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

and then install sdkmanager manually by downloading the command line tools from android studio website.